# Ember sending data from view causes error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, deprecated

I sent action from view to currents route controller, then to another controller, in order to write code once.

```
  this.get('controller.controllers.study/study').send('processPersonData', data);
```

****DEPRECATION: Action handlers implemented directly on controllers are deprecated in favor of action handlers on an `actions` object ( action: `processPersonData` on )
        at Ember.ControllerMixin.Ember.Mixin.create.deprecatedSend**

What is the right way to implement this send action? 
FYI: the send action works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This message indicates that the method handling the action should be under an 'actions' hash on the object, like so:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    someVariable: null,

    actions: {
        processPersonData: function(context) {
            //implementation
        },
        otherAction: function(context) {
            //implementation
        }
    }
});
```

It is just new semantics for action handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call an action in your controller from your view, you should use the [Em.ViewTargetActionSupport](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport.html) mixin as follows:

```
App.DashboardView = Em.View.extend(
    Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport, { // Mixin here

    functionToTriggerAction: function() {
        var data = this.get('data'); // Or wherever/whatever the data object is

        this.triggerAction({
            action: 'processPersonData',
            actionContext: data,
            target: this.get('controller') // Or wherever the action is
        });
    },
});

App.DashboardController = Em.ObjectController.extend(

    // The actions go in a hash, as buuda mentioned
    actions: 
        processPersonData: function(data) {
            // The logic you want to do on the data object goes here
        },
    },
});
```